# asp.net mvc - common code to execute when loading any page from the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, code-organization

Where would such code go? Is there a commonly executed block inside Asp.net mvc 3 application - something that gets executed every time any page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Global.asax** (ex: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126) or inside the **_Layout**, it depends on what you're doing.

Just so you know the Global.asax file is also available in ASP.NET Webforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by two ways:
First, you can inherit a base Controller from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. Then you use this base class inherits for your application. By this way, you can handle all action executions by overriding [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) method of your base controller.

Second and better solution is using [Custom Action Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=VS.98%29.aspx). Create a custom filter and register it globally in Global.asax file like this:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new YourCustomFilter());
}
```